# How to select columns from two different tables, which meet conditions based on third table

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is my problem (in MS SQL SMS 2008 R2):
I have two tables:
table1 with columns id1 name1
table2 with columns id2 name2
I also have third temporary table made from imported xls with columns name1, name2
what i want is to have select that will result in something like copy of that temporary table but with id1, id2 instead of name1, name2.
Is that even possible?

Comment: Are `name1` and `name2` the same values in your other two tables?

Comment: table1 contains users and table2 contains cars. So they're different if that's what You meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `left join` with two tables

```
select id1, id2
from tempTable T
left join table1  T1
on T.name1 = T1.name1
left join table2 T2
on T.name2 = T2.name2
```

Comment: Worked for me, except that I needed inner not left join, but based on information I gave, you couldn't figure it out. Thanks!